# How to tell if an inkjet printer can print on shrink plastic films?

Tags: printer, printing, inkjet-printer

How should I know if an inkjet printer can print on [shrink plastic films](http://www.shrinkydinks.com)?

Although printers do mention their acceptable thickness/weight, but Unfortunately shrink plastic suppliers doesn't say much about their products, specially there is no mention to media's weight.

Also do I need dye or pigment ink printer for those plastic films?

Comment: I would just call them and ask, the Shrinky Dink phone number is `800-445-7448`. Call them up and a sales rep can likely answer all of your questions about what kind of printers/ink you should use. 

When you find out report back here and you can add your own answer and let everyone else know what you found out :)

Comment: Assuming that I'm not shopping from Shrinky Dink, is there a general criteria about this?

Comment: Not really, but you can find out what shrinky dink reccomends and try it with the generic brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against trying it. There are far too many things that could go wrong

1. The shrink wrap could get mashed inside or around the printer rollers and feed.
2. <strike>It would melt due to heat in the case of a laser and similar printers.</strike>
3. The ink is unlikely to stick as printers make use of the porous nature of paper.

I would recommend if you really need to print something on shrink plastic, use some kind of [transfer method](http://www.alternativephotography.com/wp/processes/transfers-and-lifts/inkjet-wet-transfer-prints) instead.

Comment: I corrected the question, I know we should only use inkjet printers. shrink plastic films, [like Shrinky Dinks](http://www.shrinkydinks.com), are not very thin and I've seen many DIY projects on YouTube and other websites where people use these films.

Comment: My bad, I was imagining a really thin film. I suppose it would be possible, though it would have to be pretty stiff.

Comment: I just added the inkjet to the question, I've missed that before.

Comment: [This website](http://www.uline.com/BL_2403/Reynolds-PVC-Shrink-Film) has a catalog of weight/length, but I don't believe it is relevant. The only thing that matters is if the wrap is think enough it be gripped by the print rollers, which I expect it is.